# How to convert coordinate systems between pygame/pybpox2d and matlpotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pygame, box2d, coordinate-systems

Heavily Edited:

I am trying to use matplotlib to plot and analyse the behaviour of an agent in a simulation that is run using pygame. I have tried plotting in matplotlib using the pixel values which pygame uses to draw the image. The problem is that the pygame representation and the matplotlib plots are a little different, the white and coloured patches in the upper half do not align, and I cannot ascertain why. The following code produces the matplotlib plot using the pixel values that pygame uses:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
patch_positions = [(401.0, 212.0),
                   (266.0, 455.0),
                   (77.0, 293.0),
                   (131.0, 104.0),
                   (347.0, 563.0),
                   (104.0, 579.0),
                   (482.0, 104.0),
                   (563.0, 185.0),
                   (563.0, 536.0)]

reward_positions = [(131.0, 158.0),
                   (293.0, 482.0),
                   (455.0, 185.0)]

patch_colors = [(0.627, 0.627, 0.627),
                    (0, 1, 0),
                    (0, 0, 1),
                    (1, 0, 0),
                    (0.2, 0.8, 1),
                    (0.4, 0.2, 0),
                    (0.3, 0, 0.6),
                    (0, 0.4, 0),
                    (1, 0.2, 0.6)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize, dpi=100)

ax.set_facecolor("black")
ax.set_xlim(left=0, right=640)
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0, top=640)

for pos,col in zip(patch_positions,patch_colors):
    patch = plt.Circle(pos, 27, color=col)
    ax.add_artist(patch)

for pos in reward_positions:
    patch = plt.Circle(pos, 14, color=(1,1,1))
    ax.add_artist(patch)

ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

[image: pygame]

[image: matplotlib]

Comment: While this may be a valid problem, I don't think anyone will understand it with the information provided here. What is the code that needs to be run to observe the problem? In how far is what you get different from what you expect?

Comment: I am struggling to make a reproducible example at the moment, I will continue trying to make one.